# JW Player doesn't work on https

Tags: http, ssl, https, jwplayer

I am using a jw player in a page like domain.com/page

when I open this page on http the player works well but when I open it on https is shows only loading... and doesn't play.

Comment: show browser console log

Answer (score 0):

If the content is not served over https it will not play in an https page.